# Open new tab Selenium 3.0 and geckodriver using control T does not work

Tags: geckodriver, selenium3

Using Keys.CTRL + t, is not opening new tab in Selenium 3.0 with gecko driver

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

Answer (score 0):

once I tried Robot for that, like -

```
try{
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    }catch (AWTException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); // Or do whatever in here
    }
```

I don't really sure in relation of keys in here (VK_CONTROL and VK_T), that's what you'll have to find out, but it worked for me.
P.S.
Probably, you'll have to release keys after.